# How to turn down PHP error logging

Tags: php, apache, logging

We recently upgraded a server from PHP4 to PHP5.4

There is an application running that is logging a lot of errors in the log file.  Most of them are deprecated errors, or some minor things due to the change in PHP versions.

I don't have time to fix all the problems right now, but the error_log file has ballooned to 10G in just a few days.

In php.ini I set 
log_errors = Off

What else can I do ?

Comment: look at fixing those errors

Comment: Are you still having issues after you turned off logging of errors?

Comment: you must have edited the wrong php.ini file, or you need to restart the webserver to get the webserver processes to reload the php config. use phpinfo() to find the location of the correct php.ini. You don't need to change the error reporting level, turning off log_errors is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which errors you want to report, if any.  If you don't want any errors to be reported (bad idea, I think), go with:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

At the top of the script.

If you only want to turn off the deprecated errors, you would need to use some [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) using the [predefined error constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). I believe the following would work and fit what you have in mind:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_DEPRECATED & E_STRICT & E_NOTICE))
```

This would still leave in fatal errors and catchable errors, (2 of those 3 will halt the script so they are good to catch), but leave out the "your script is old" type errors.

It is also possible to send the less desired errors to another error log, so that they can be dealt with later, but not clog the main error log. Ask if interested.

### Quick Edit:

Because `E_STRICT` is not included in `E_ALL`, the above would turn *on* `E_STRICT` (which is only confusing when we assume that **ALL** means, well, all of them (all bits flipped).  So this would produce the desired result of the those three errors being turned off:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_DEPRECATED & E_NOTICE))
```

or, to eat my words on the comment on zuul's answer, this would also work (though the logic hurts my head):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE))
```

Also, since you mentioned Apache specifically, you should know that you can't use the predefined error constants outside of a PHP script, you have to use the actual bitmask values. In this case, you would add the following to the config or htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 22519
```

I'm not finding anywhere in the documentation where bitwise operations are supported in this scenario, so if you wanted to tweak the error_reporting level, you could simply create a php script with the following:

```
echo E_ALL & ~(E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);
```

Which will output the decimal form of that bitmask to use (obviously changing the constants to match what you want to turn off).

Comment: +'d, by the elaborate answer with link to documentation! I'm too damn sleepy at this late hour...

Comment: @Zuul : Awww, sorry for the comment asking for more elaboration then. I've been up for 30 hours and don't get to sleep for awhile, so my elaboration was partly to keep my brain awake.

Answer (score 3):

**Simply turn off these warnings in your php.ini**

```
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

**in run time:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` is equivalent to `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`, at least according to the php example on bitwise operators. Will post again to confirm.

Comment: Yep, both come out to 30711 in decimal.  I'm not sure if I prefer the `XOR` or the `AND NOT` more in terms of readability, but I think the `XOR` does allow for easier grouping of errors to switch off, as in my example.  If you could provide an example of how to use the `AND NOT` for both `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_STRICT`, that would be really helpful for both the OP and future readers.

Comment: Yap, I was reading and they achieve the same end goal, all errors but the `E_DEPRECATED`: either by using `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` or `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`.

Comment: Anyway, by the documentation, the declaration as `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED)` seems to be more efficient! Non the less, I don't see what much of a difference can it make :)

Comment: Read my addendum to see me eat some crow. Because `E_ALL` excludes `E_STRICT`, using `& ~` allows for explicitly turning `E_STRICT` off (meaning leaving it off), rather than turning it on.  crazyness.

Comment: lol, I've got my head spinning! Need some sleep :) I'll dig deeper on this issue tomorrow! ;)  ps: I've read your addendum, still spinning over here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following to the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_NONE);
```

Comment: Should be 0, there is no E_NONE: _PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant E_NONE_